# Formatting columns with qgrid, pandas and ipython notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm using [qgrid](https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid) to visualise pandas data in ipython notebooks. Qgrid uses the SlickGrids JS library to render the table. I would like to format numbers as financial or other formats. SlickGrids seems to support some column formatting functionality which appears to be accessible through the `qgrid.show_grid()` `grid_options` parameter, but I can't quite grasp how to use it to format columns.

Comment: create a minimal working example that shows us what you've tried and where it went wrong.